# Como utilizar uma cláusula join adicionando uma coluna que indique a existência de uma ligação

Tags: mysql, join

Tenho duas tabelas

```
Horas (id, aluno_id, atividade_id)
```

e

```
Atividades (id, emblema_id)
```

Além de retornar todos os emblemas, preciso retornar uma coluna que me diga se aquele aluno o possui. Pra saber se ele possui, basta que ele tenha ganhado horas na atividade.

Das duas formas que tentei, consegui retornar somente os emblemas que ele possuia e todos os emblemas de uma vez, mas sem discriminar qual daqueles ele realmente possuia.
Como exemplo das tabelas Horas e Atividades preenchidas, respectivamente, segue:

```
id | aluno_id | atividade_id
1  |    1     | 1


id | emblema_id
1  | 1
2  | 2
```

O resultado esperado deve ser:

```
emblema_id | possui
    1      | Sim
    2      | Não
         ...
```

No exemplo de resultado esperado acima, eu demonstro que o aluno possui o emblema 1 porque ganhou horas na atividade correspondente. Porém, não possui o emblema 2, pois não ganhou horas.

Comment: Como que saberei que como juntar as tabelas? Coloca a estrutura exata das mesmas e uns 3 dados de exemplo pra gente pode se espelhar com mais precissão

Comment: Como juntar as tabelas? Na tabela horas o atributo atividade_id corresponde ao id de Atividades

Comment: @CayoDaSilvaLima Quanto a estrutura exata da tabela, os dados relevantes são esses mesmo. Adicionei um exemplo das tabelas preenchidas que casa com o resultado esperado. Veja se é suficiente. Quan

Comment: @MarceloAugusto sua pergunta não está clara o suficiente. Poste o modo que você está fazendo.

Answer (score 0):

Faça um `LEFT JOIN` e coloque um `if` para verificar se o `b.id` é nulo ou não:

```
SELECT a.`emblema_id`, IF(b.`id` IS NOT NULL, "SIM", "NÃO") AS 'possui' FROM `Atividades` a
LEFT JOIN `Horas` b ON a.`id` = b.`atividade_id` AND b.`aluno_id` = 1
GROUP BY b.`aluno_id`, b.`atividade_id`;
```

Comment: Apenas um erro foi apresentado. Você usou b.emblema_id, mas não referenciou o b fora da sub-select. Tentei modificar mas não retornou o resultado esperado.

Comment: Alterei o `SELECT`, veja se agora atende

Comment: A coluna foi criada como eu falei, porém somente os emblemas que o aluno conquistou foram retornados. Veja que no resultado esperado o emblema que ele não conquistou está marcado como 'Não'

Comment: Fiz invertido, vou corrigir

Comment: Veja agora se funciona

Comment: Apresentou erro, acredito eu corresponde a alguma coluna que esteja faltando no group by

Comment: Qual erro apresentou?

Comment: Agora alterei, tive que tirar o `where` e colocar a verificação do aluno no `ON`.

Comment: O erro permaneceu. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'minhazoras.a.emblema_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Fiz uma alteração no group by e aparentemente retornou como eu esperava. Coloquei o group by pro b.emblema_id e 'possui'